# java.lang.Exception: TestComplete/TestExecute not found

Tags: java, cucumber, testcomplete, jacob

I want to invoke testcomplete's keyword tests from my java project using BDD styled testscripts. All the steps mentioned on this [tutorial](https://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/bdd-cucumber-and-testcomplete/) are followed. The execution fails with following stacktrace :

```
java.lang.Exception: TestComplete/TestExecute not found
at com.smartbear.cucumber.TestComplete.<init>(TestComplete.java:42)
at com.example.testingNotepad.World.TC(Steps.java:64)
at com.example.testingNotepad.Steps.before(Steps.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Please suggest a way to trigger testcomplete keyword tests.

Comment: It's seems that the library from the article can't find info about installed TestComplete\TestExecute in the system registry. It uses "TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication" and "TestExecute.TestExecuteApplication" program IDs to find one of installed application. Make sure you have an appropriate key. The simplest solution I see - reinstall TestComplete or TestExecute. The installer must put correct keys to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same errors and I have found my solution: "it would make sense to reinstall TestComplete with the disabled antivirus and Windows Firewall. Just in case, you can try disabling the Windows Store applications support in TestComplete (Tools->Options->Engines->General->Enable support for testing Windows Store applications). Perhaps, this will help." It works for me. Hope this will also help you!